# Список TestCase из TFS

Tags: запрос, case, tfs

При получении списка TestCase я получаю не только те, которые отображаются на tfs, но и те которых там нет. Вот код:

```
ITestManagmentService service = (ITestManagmentService)tfsCollection.GetService(typeof(ITestManagmentService));
ITestManagmentTeamProject myTestManagmentTeamProject = service.GetTeamProject(TeamProject);
List<ITestCase> testCase = myTestManagmentTeamProject.TestCases.Query("SELECT * FROM WorkItems").ToList();
```

Как это исправить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скорее всего попадают тесткейсы из других проектов. Ограничьте запрос по шаблону:

> SELECT [System.Id] FROM WorkItems WHERE [Team Project] = '{0}'

Доработанный пример:

```
        WorkItemStore workItemStore = new WorkItemStore(service_url);

        ITestManagementService testclient = workItemStore.TeamProjectCollection.GetService<ITestManagementService>();
        ITestManagementTeamProject myTestManagmentTeamProject = testclient.GetTeamProject(TeamProjectName); 

        string query = String.Format("SELECT [System.Id] FROM WorkItems WHERE [Team Project] = '{0}'", TeamProjectName);

        List<ITestCase> testCase = myTestManagmentTeamProject.TestCases.Query(query).ToList();
```